# Excel Large Data to Summary Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

In the attached excel workbook contains 2 sheets, First one is data and second one is Result.

In the Data sheet, "A" column contains the length (10 meter) and "B" column contains the type of pole to be used.

In the Result sheet which is summary of Data sheet, Column "A" should consist of start and Column "B" column contains the type of pole to be used. Is there any formula is automate the table.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CRw3Wy2ELyBjl07onnWXPIAprDiraJTC

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**:Caveat:**

*Since `pole type` has odd combinations (Duplicate groups), therefore the suggested method is not as good and efficient as expected, but ultimately it's working.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Formula in cell `C41` for helper data:

  `=IF(B41=B41,COUNTIF(B$41:B41,B41),"")`
- Enter Pole type in column `F`.

**N.B**

- For Pole list, formula to create unique list was expected. But due to duplicate groups, I was unable to do so.
- **If reader can do this please suggest me to edit it.**
- An array (CSE) formula Formula in cell `D41`:

  ```
  {=MIN(IF($B$41:$B$65=$F41,IF($C$41:$C$65>=1,IF($C$41:$C$65<=6,$A$41:$A$65))))}
  ```
- An array (CSE) Formula in cell `E41`:

  ```
  {=MAX(IF($B$41:$B$65=$F41,IF($C$41:$C$65>=1,IF($C$41:$C$65<=6,$A$41:$A$65))))}
  ```

**N.B.**

- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.
- Copy it down.

**Do correction in both formula as show below.**

For 1st As: `IF($C$41:$C$65>=1,IF($C$41:$C$65<=6`

For 1st Bs: `IF($C$41:$C$65>=1,IF($C$41:$C$65<=5`

For Cs    : `IF($C$41:$C$65>=1,IF($C$41:$C$65<=5`

For Ds    : `IF($C$41:$C$65>=1,IF($C$41:$C$65<=3`

For 2nd As: `IF($C$41:$C$65>=7,IF($C$41:$C$65<=9`

For 2nd Bs: `IF($C$41:$C$65>=6,IF($C$41:$C$65<=8`

- *For neatness later on you may hide Helper Column.*

---

**:My Suggestion:**

*If you allow entire data to be sorted in ascending order, then it will turn into simple group and entire operation become must easier, and a efficient method can be applied as shown below.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- An arry (CSE) formula in cell `L41`:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($I$41:$I$65,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($L$40:L40,$I$41:$I$65),0)),"")}
  ```
- Enter Array (CSE) formula in cell `J41`:

  `{=MIN(IF($I$41:$I$65=$L41,$H$41:$H$65))}`
- An array (CSE) formula in cell `K41`:

  `{=MAX(($I$41:$I$65=$L41)*$H$41:$H$65)}`

**N.B.**

- *Finish above shown array formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**, and fill down.*
- *Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Answer (score 0):

Although you don't have `vba` as a tag, it is pretty simple and easily adaptable to your problem to use a vba Macro.

To enter this Macro (Sub), <kbd>alt-F11</kbd> opens the Visual Basic Editor.
Ensure your project is highlighted in the `Project Explorer` window.
Then, from the top menu, select `Insert/Module` and
paste the code below into the window that opens.

To use this Macro (Sub), <kbd>alt-F8</kbd> opens the macro dialog box. Select the macro by name, and <kbd>RUN</kbd>.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Summarize()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim D As Object
    Dim I As Long, V As Variant

'Set data and results worksheets, range
Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Data")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("Result")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 1)

'read data into vba variant array (faster processing)
With wsSrc
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
End With

'collect Data Groups
Set D = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 1) 'skip the header row
    If vSrc(I - 1, 2) <> vSrc(I, 2) Then
        D.Add Key:=vSrc(I, 1), Item:=vSrc(I, 2)
    End If
Next I

'create results array
ReDim vRes(0 To D.Count, 1 To 3)

'Header row
vRes(0, 1) = "Start"
vRes(0, 2) = "End"
vRes(0, 3) = "Type"

'Data
I = 0
For Each V In D
    I = I + 1

    'Start Data
    If I = 1 Then
        vRes(I, 1) = 0
    Else
        vRes(I, 1) = V
    End If

    'Type Data
    vRes(I, 3) = D(V)
Next V

'End data
I = 2
Do Until I > UBound(vRes, 1)
    vRes(I - 1, 2) = vRes(I, 1)
    I = I + 1
Loop

'Write to the worksheets
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(rowsize:=UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, columnsize:=UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    With .Rows(1)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

**Results from your Data**

[image]